# Regroup the segmented image according to its source image

Tags: java, image

I have read from a list of image from a folder and then do cropping and segmented the character from the image. Then the file created is save to another folder with new name. For example the first source image(image1) I have segmented 7 new character images and it goes on with the next image.

My question is how can I regroup these images according to their source image like assigning them (im01-im07 is from source image1) and so on. This is the code:

```
for (int sf = 0; sf < listOfSrcFFiles.length; sf++) {
    File imgFile = listOfSrcFFiles[sf];
    String fileName = imgFile.getName();
    if (fileName.equals("Thumbs.db")) {
        imgFile.delete();   
    } else {
        try{
            Mat img_grayROI = Highgui.imread(imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
            Rect roi = new Rect(300, 200, 450, 200);
            Mat cropped = new Mat(img_grayROI, roi);

            Imgproc.threshold(cropped, cropped, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

            Point shift = new Point(0, 150);
            Mat result = cropped;

            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();


            Imgproc.findContours(result, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            Imgproc.floodFill(result, new Mat(), shift, new Scalar(255, 0, 0));

            Core.bitwise_not(result, result);

            for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
                if (Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)) > 50) {
                    Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));

                    /*if (rect.height > 25 && rect.height < 50 && rect.width > 10 && rect.width < 50) {*/
                    if (rect.height > 25 && rect.width < 25) {
                        Core.rectangle(result, rect.tl(), rect.br(), new Scalar(0, 0, 0));

                        Mat crop = new Mat(result, rect);
                        Highgui.imwrite(tmpFolder + fSprator + sf + "" + i + ".bmp", crop);
                    }
                }

            }
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

This is so I can later save them into text file and separated them according to their source image name.

Thank you, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution is to create a bean to hold the results.

Eg:

```
public class TransformResult {
    private File input;
    private List<File> transformedFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters / setters
}

public List<TransformResult> doTransform(File listOfSrcFFiles) {
    List<TransformResult> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File srcFile : listOfSrcFFiles) {
        if (...) {
           TransformResult result = new TransformResult(srcFile);
           for (...) {
              if (...) {
                  File transformed = doSomeTransformation(srcFile);
                  result.getTransformedFiles().add(transformed);
              }
           }
           results.add(result);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry but can you explain in details on how to do it. I am not clear